# How to install Office Pro Plus 2010 on WIndows 11 Home

Tags: installation, windows-11, microsoft-office-2010

I attempted to install Office Professional Pro 2010 on a new PC running Windows 11 Home version 22H2 OS Build 22621.963

During the installation, I got a popup dialog with the message:

```
Could not find Proplusr.WW\ProPrWW2.cab. Browse to a valid installation source then click OK.
```

I browsed to the directory Proplusr (which exists on the install disk and contains a file ProPrWW2.cab) and click on OK.

The installation then fails with the following MessageBox:

```
Setup
---------------------------
Invalid location.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

My new PC had a trial version of Office 365 installed: I uninstalled it so see if that would help, but I still get the same error.

I've also tried other tips I've found on the web, e.g. copying files from the installation disk to the local disk, but this didn't help.

The same install disk works fine on Windows 10, so it doesn't look like file corruption.

Can anyone help?

Comment: [Does](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/following-error-set-up-can-not-find/141d49bb-6165-400e-9e9a-a546cb295d5e) solution work for you?

Comment: @Ramhound - no that didn't work, I tried uninstalling the trial version of Office 365 and it didn't help

Comment: Your question was not clear and your answer does not relate to what you asked.  I have Office 2010 running in a VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that Office 2010 is out of support, but I need it mainly for testing Office VBA 2010 applications that I've developed in the dim and distant past and don't want to migrate to a newer version of Office.

I also wanted to install other software (e.g. Microsoft Money 98) which seems to be incompatible with Windows 11, and for which there isn't a better new alternative.

I solved my immediate problem by enabling Hyper-V on my Windows 11 Home PC, after which I was able to install an older version of Windows as a guest OS, into which I installed the problematic applications.

Answer (score -1):

if your setup file is one Exe file, try to extract the setup file and then try to install:

1. Save the downloaded  on to the desktop.
2. press keys win+R  open Run window
3. Click on the Office installation executable file and drag and drop it into the ‘Run’ command to get the file name and its location in the ‘Run’ command's open tab.
4. Go to the run command > press ‘End’ button on the keyboard > press the ‘Space’ key > type ‘/extract’ without quotes > OK
   Example: C:\User\Desktop.....OfficeSetup.exe /extract
5. You will a prompt to store extracted files, Click on Desktop >Make a new folder > name the folder as ‘Office Setup’ > OK
6. Wait until the file extraction completes > Open the ‘Office Setup’ folder from desktop > Double click on Setup file and try installing the Office suite.

if not fix the issue then re-download Office and then try to install Office 2010.
رسانه رهانش